# React Native - "@drawable/background_splash" Error

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

Hi I used This Article to Changing my Splash Screen for android via react native But I Got This Error: [Article Link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
D:\Projects 2016\Web\Android\3 Splash Project\Mohajerkade\android\app\build\inte
rmediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:1365:47-74: AAPT: No resource found
 that matches the given name (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '@drawabl
e/background_splash').

Failed to generate resource table for split ''
D:\Projects 2016\Web\Android\3 Splash Project\Mohajerkade\android\app\build\inte
rmediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:1365: error: Error: No resource fou
nd that matches the given name (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '@drawa
ble/background_splash').


:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

`@drawable/background_splash` is in Style.xml and what should I do?

Comment: Have you created the background_splash.xml file? That error makes me seem that you haven't. I've actually got a step-by-step article on adding a splash screen to React Native (the article you linked to is the basis for Android - I just made it focused on RN). https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae

Comment: Solved. Thanks For Your Amazing Tutorial.  @spencer-carli

Comment: @spencer-carli , I have  White page showing after splash screen before app, What Should I Do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My article was basis for android and this article focused on RN (https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae)

**Awnsered By spencer carli**

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be caused by file permissions. My operating system is Win10. I ran the terminal as an administrator. After `react-native run-android`